# issue with mcustomScroller in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a long list of li's in Ui in which I have applied `mCustomScrollbar` for scrolling it. Each `li` has a check box in it.

But when I am scrolling down and clicking anywhere other than that check box, the scroller scrolls up. I have to click very precisely into the checkbox only. Why is this happening?

html snapshot :

```
 <div id="tab-all" class="tab-content price_rule_checkbox_listing">
 <ul id="leftSection">
    <li><input type="checkbox" class="left select-all"><h3>Select all</h3><div class="clear"></div></li>
    <li class="sub_checkbox_list_box"><input type="checkbox" class="left selector" value=13><h3>rule1</h3><div class="clear"></div></li>
    .....
    <li class="sub_checkbox_list_box"><input type="checkbox" class="left selector" value=22><h3>rule10</h3><div class="clear"></div></li>
```

Scroller function :

```
scrollifyFilter('#leftSection');//in javascript scroller is called like this.


function scrollifyFilter(selector) {
if ($(selector).hasClass('mCustomScrollbar')) {
    return
}
$(selector).mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollInertia : 600,
    advanced : {
        updateOnContentResize : true
    },
    verticalScroll : true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the mCustomScrollbar to a `<div>` rather than a `<ul>`.

Example:

```
<div id="ID_TO_ATTACH_SCROLLBAR">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you place the `<ul>` inside the `<div>`? I will edit my answer.

Comment: Strange, I used the scrollbar taken from this site. And it works for me. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: yes sir i am using the same scroller. when i apply it to ul it works but in case of div it just doesnt appear. one thing i have noticed when i apply to div the ul doesnt gets mcustomscroller bar class added to it(container class).

Comment: Did you set all the necessary css styles to the div? Like overflow and height?